# Efficient storage & retrieval of category to tags data

Tags: sql, tagging, key-value

I have a following situation in my project. There are some tag values which are associated to a single category.

Example:

```
Fruits : Apple, Banana, Grape
Vegetables: Tomato, Cabbage, Brinjal
```

Now, for this I use a simple table in database with two columns, `Category`, `Tag`, and I store "Fruits" in `Category` column and "Apple, Banana, Grape" in `Tag` column (each tag separated by coma). And when I query a single Category using simple SQL statement like `select tag from TagsCollection where category='Fruits';` I get a string with all the tags that belong to "Fruits" category. Note that the table will have only single instance of any particular Category as record. And than I need all the tags to be separated for further processing, so I split the string on comas in my programming language (Java, here).

Now, what can be an ideal way to implement something like this? do I proceed with RDBMS-way of storage (MySQL, to be precise) or is there any other faster way to store & retrieve such type of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current design violates first normal form, since you have multiple values in a single row of a single column. Also, any query on tag values is likely to perform poorly.

A normalised design would retain Category and Tag columns, but would have a separate row for each combination of Category and Tag - like so:

```
Category  Tag
Fruits    Apple
Fruits    Banana
Fruits    Grape
...
```

Comment: I intentionally used multi-value attribute ignoring any normal forms for hoping to get any better solution. So having it stored this way, I can further use something like HashTable for each category on the programming front for efficient matching. However, is there any non-database way to store information like this? some sort of XML? (not aware of XML based storages)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the expected size of your database, and TagsCollection table in particular.

You can choose either RDBMS design in case you don't expect huge number of records (by huge I mean billions of records and tens or hundreds of queries per second), or go for the NoSQL system, one of:

- http://cassandra.apache.org/
- http://project-voldemort.com/
- http://www.mongodb.org/